# Petri net boundedness

Tags: petri-net

I want to ask about petri net(PN) boundedness. When I have a state `s1 = (2 0 0)` then i  find state `s2 = (2 0 1)` so since `s1 < s2` can I declare PN as NOT bounded ? Because when  I have this PN:
[image: PN]

PN is bounded but u can find there (2 0 0) < (2 0 1).
So my question is. Am I wrong about boundedness of petri net or is something wrong with PT on the picture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This net is bounded. You can check this by building its reachability graph.

Initially only one transition `t1` is enabled. Therefore `s1=(2 0 0)` has only one successor state `s2 = (1 1 0)`. Here is the full reachability graph

[image: reachability graph of the Petri net]

Also observe that there is no transition that has more outgoing arcs than incoming arcs, therefore the number of tokens in the net cannot increase. This is called *an invariant*. From this observation you can derive that the state `(2 0 1)` can never be reached from `(2 0 0)`.